# MVC 4 client side validation to be shown in a dialog

Tags: asp.net-mvc-3, validation, asp.net-mvc-4, kendo-ui, unobtrusive-validation

I am using MVC4.

I have a ViewModel that has been decorated with the `[Required()]` validation attribute.

When the form is submitted the client validation is fired and is displayed in-line (using a validation summary), so everything works as it should.

How do I display the validation in a dialog instead of in-line?

Here is the sample code from the MVC 4 Internet application template

```
public class RegisterModel
    {
        [Required]
        [Display(Name = "User name")]
        public string UserName { get; set; }

        [Required]
        [StringLength(100, ErrorMessage = "The {0} must be at least {2} characters long.", MinimumLength = 6)]
        [DataType(DataType.Password)]
        [Display(Name = "Password")]
        public string Password { get; set; }

        [DataType(DataType.Password)]
        [Display(Name = "Confirm password")]
        [Compare("Password", ErrorMessage = "The password and confirmation password do not match.")]
        public string ConfirmPassword { get; set; }
    }


@model MvcApplication2.Models.RegisterModel
@{
    ViewBag.Title = "Register";
}

<hgroup class="title">
    <h1>@ViewBag.Title.</h1>
    <h2>Create a new account.</h2>
</hgroup>

@using (Html.BeginForm()) {
    @Html.AntiForgeryToken()
    @Html.ValidationSummary()

    <fieldset>
        <legend>Registration Form</legend>
        <ol>
            <li>
                @Html.LabelFor(m => m.UserName)
                @Html.TextBoxFor(m => m.UserName)
            </li>
            <li>
                @Html.LabelFor(m => m.Password)
                @Html.PasswordFor(m => m.Password)
            </li>
            <li>
                @Html.LabelFor(m => m.ConfirmPassword)
                @Html.PasswordFor(m => m.ConfirmPassword)
            </li>
        </ol>
        <input type="submit" value="Register" />
    </fieldset>
}

@section Scripts {
    @Scripts.Render("~/bundles/jqueryval")
}
```

So when I click the submit button without any data in the textboxes, the error message is displayed at the top in a validation summary.

Currently I am using Kendo ui dialogs to show all the errors returned by the server.  So what I am trying to do is unify the error messages, so that they are all shown in a similar fashion.

Currently I just want to know how to hook into the client side validation, so I can call the Kendo ui dialog with the error details..

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

All I needed was the following, Jquery validation

```
$(function () {
    $("form").bind("invalid-form", function (e, validator) {
        //your logic
    });
});
```

Big thanks to Dan at Kendo UI

Answer (score 0):

Instead of having all the `@Html.ValidationMessageFor( ...` when submitting if it is not valid call show a dialog and with [`numberOfInvalids()`](http://jqueryvalidation.org/Validator.numberOfInvalids) you can retrieve the errors and their messages and just show them in a dialog.